# Load term by name

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7, we can load the term using name for ex. `taxonomy_get_term_by_name($name)`

Is there any way to load term via given name in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This functionality appears to be deprecated in Drupal 8.
Use the [taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name/8.2.x) function instead.

Example

```
<?php

  /**
   * Utility: find term by name and vid.
   * @param null $name
   *  Term name
   * @param null $vid
   *  Term vid
   * @return int
   *  Term id or 0 if none.
   */
  protected function getTidByName($name = NULL, $vid = NULL) {
    $properties = [];
    if (!empty($name)) {
      $properties['name'] = $name;
    }
    if (!empty($vid)) {
      $properties['vid'] = $vid;
    }
    $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties($properties);
    $term = reset($terms);

    return !empty($term) ? $term->id() : 0;
  }

?>
```

Comment: Linked blog post doesn't seem to load anymore. Found this one that may be helpful for others trying to figure this out. https://www.btmash.com/article/2016-04-26/saving-and-retrieving-taxonomy-terms-programmatically-drupal-8

Comment: From performance perspective, which is more effective - \Drupal::entityManager() or taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name?

Answer (score 38):

You can use snippet code like by using [entityTypeManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityTypeManager/8.2.x) :

```
$term_name = 'Term Name';
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
      ->loadByProperties(['name' => $term_name]);
```

Comment: Maybe also pass the `'vid'` vocabulary ID along like in the answer by @RenukaKulkarni below. Imagine having multiple vocabularies and every vocabulary has a term with the `$term_name = 'Term Name'`.

Answer (score 9):

To load a single term ID by term name and vocabulary in Drupal 8 you can use the following snippet.

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadByProperties(['name' => $term_name, 'vid' => 'job_category']);
$term = reset($term);
$term_id = $term->id();
```

Comment: I just needed the term ID as well and just used $term_tid = array_keys($term)[0];

Answer (score 2):

As per [Renamed the taxonomy functions that returned multiple values](https://www.drupal.org/node/1413672), [`taxonomy_get_term_by_name($name, $vocabulary = NULL)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7.x) has been renamed [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($name, $vocabulary = NULL)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name/8.2.x). If you look at the code of the first function and you compare it with the code of the second function, you will notice that the most relevant difference is having replaced the call to [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), $conditions)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7.x) with the call to [`entity_load_multiple_by_properties('taxonomy_term', $values)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_load_multiple_by_properties/8.2.x).

```
// Drupal 7
function taxonomy_get_term_by_name($name, $vocabulary = NULL) {
  $conditions = array('name' => trim($name));
  if (isset($vocabulary)) {
    $vocabularies = taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names();
    if (isset($vocabularies[$vocabulary])) {
      $conditions['vid'] = $vocabularies[$vocabulary]->vid;
    }
    else {
      // Return an empty array when filtering by a non-existing vocabulary.
      return array();
    }
  }
  return taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), $conditions);
}
```

```
// Drupal 8
function taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($name, $vocabulary = NULL) {
  $values = array('name' => trim($name));
  if (isset($vocabulary)) {
    $vocabularies = taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names();
    if (isset($vocabularies[$vocabulary])) {
      $values['vid'] = $vocabulary;
    }
    else {
      // Return an empty array when filtering by a non-existing vocabulary.
      return array();
    }
  }
  return entity_load_multiple_by_properties('taxonomy_term', $values);
}
```

Since `taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name()` has not been marked as deprecated, you can still use that function where you used to use `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()`. They both require the same arguments, so converting code for Drupal 7 in code for Drupal 8, in this case, is just matter of replacing the function name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use entity field queries to load by fields on the term

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
          ->condition('field_my_field_name', 'Whatever Value')
          ->execute();
```